# import libs.solaris as sol but No module named 'gdal'

Tags: python, solaris, gdal

Recently, I was going through some tutorials but having a problem importing external modules. The error shows as below:

`import libs.solaris as sol`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ef528ac68d82> in <module>
----> 1 import libs.solaris as sol

~/SageMaker/aws-open-data-satellite-lidar-tutorial/libs/solaris/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import bin, data, eval, nets, raster, tile, utils, vector
      2 
      3 __version__ = "0.2.2"

~/SageMaker/aws-open-data-satellite-lidar-tutorial/libs/solaris/data/__init__.py in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import geopandas as gpd
----> 4 import gdal
      5 import rasterio
      6 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

But when I tried  `!pip install gdal` it shows:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tutorial_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.2.1)
```

Can anyone instruct me on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to use

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

or downgrade the version of your gdal library.

See https://gdal.org/api/python.html#imports